# Change to active form:

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> Such rumors are commonly heard these days.

I converted this as:

> We hear these rumors commonly these days.

Is it the correct active form?

Comment: You attempt is in the active voice.  We have to create a subject since there was none in the original.  "We" is a decent choice.

Comment: It's quite often to hear such rumors these days.

Comment: @Cardinal that sentence is not grammatical and if you corrected it so it was, it would be passive voice.

Comment: The passive counterpart is an unstated group of people.  Therefore *people hear these rumors* would be my first thought but *we* is an acceptable substitution, since it implies that the *we* doing the hearing are people.  I up-voted @Tᴚoɯɐuo's earlier comment to that effect.

Comment: @Brillig Is it grammatically wrong? or It's unidiomatic? It's interesting!

Comment: It's generally good style to keep the adverb close to the verb it modifies: "We commonly hear such rumors these days".  Also I try to avoid repeating the same word in a sentence, unless it serves some purpose ... but I admit this takes some practice .

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion is valid, but would mark you as not being a native speaker of English. Idiomatic English normally places the adverb close to the verb it modifies, so "*We commonly hear such rumors these days.*" would be a better formulation. Another alternative, perceived as more formal (or perhaps more British, as opposed to more American), might be to use the indefinite subject *one*: *One commonly hears such rumors these days.*