# What is wrong in "It's quite often to hear such rumors these days."?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

In [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134737/change-to-active-form?noredirect=1#comment274840_134737), which asks for transforming a sentence from passive voice to active, I left a comment as

> It's quite often to hear such rumors these days.

However, @Brillig told me that sentence is not grammatically correct.

I want to know which part of this sentence is at odds with grammar. I am saying that because I asked them if my sentence is unidiomatic or ungrammatical and they said it's ungrammatical.

Comment: The "dummy it" is the problem here. You're trying to use it unidiomatically. You could say instead: _"It's quite often **that we** hear such rumors these days."_

Comment: That's better, but it still doesn't sound quite right to me. It would be better to say _"We quite often hear such rumors these days."_ Even that is a bit stilted; I would probably leave out the "quite" in this context: _"We often hear such rumors these days."_

Comment: @Cardinal One thing to understand about American English is that you can't always find a grammatical rule to know what will sound right to the native ear. The language just doesn't work that way. Some things will sound right; others won't. And quite often, the only way to know is to ask a native speaker if it sounds right or if they would word it differently.

Comment: I think what is strangest about the original question's example is the phrase "It's <adverb> to <verb>" is never used, at least that I can think of.  That ordering is typically "It's <adjective> to <verb>", which means that for <a subject> to <verb> induces a state in the subject of feeling or being more <adjective>.  It has nothing to do with the way in which <subject> <verb>-ed. Examples: "It's fun to drive", or "It's good to be king".

Comment: I think In the original construction, the dummy 'it' refers to the subject that hears the rumor; the subject is a noun and it's improper to apply an adverb to a noun.  In the "quite often that we" construction, the dummy 'it' no longer refers to the hearing subject, because that subject ("we") is explicit.  Instead the dummy it refers to the action of hearing; the action is  a verb and it is proper to apply an adverb to a verb.  I do agree with Michael that, while technically correct, this construction sounds unusual and stilted.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The sentence structure with the copula 'be' requires a complement. An adjective, a noun or a noun phrase must follow *is*. But there is none of these things in the sentence.

The problem is with the word "often". It is an adverb (of frequency) and as such it is used for modifying action verbs or adjectives (none of which is the case). As an adverb it cannot be a complement of the sentence subject "it".

A correct sentence would be:

> It's quite *common* to hear such rumors these days.

where *common* *is* an adjective, hence fulfilling the minimal requirement for completing the phrase "It is quite...".

Comment: Yet _"It is quite often that we hear..."_ is, erm, quite idiomatic and proper, where _often_ modifies _hear_. The dummy it forgives a multitude of sins.

Comment: This point of yours should definitely be taken into account with my answer. The sentence can be simplified by getting rid of the dummy construction: "We hear such rumors quite often these days." Right?

Comment: Aye, but he wants to use the dummy it. I think the complement can be the substantival "that" clause (which is adjectival): _"that we hear_". But it might take @JohnLawler to untangle this.

Comment: @P. E. Dant (I like your username) I was wondering if "it" is really a dummy. The Wikipedia Article "Dummy pronoun" says: _"A dummy pronoun, also called an expletive pronoun or pleonastic pronoun, is a pronoun used for syntax without explicit meaning."_ But is this condition really fulfilled in our case? I do understand that _it_ is a dummy in a sentence like "It's raining." But in our sentence, doesn't 'it' refer to" to hear such rumors"?! Hence the sentence could be reformulated as follows: "To hear such rumors is quite common these days." Or do I miss the point?

Comment: @AshwinSchumann Of course it's a dummy subject. It's just a placeholder in the extraposed construction!

Comment: @P. E. Dant - I guess I didn't understand the concept of dummy pronoun very well and concluded too hastily from its Wikipedia definition! This Wikipedia definition, I feel though, stands in contradiction to the examples it provides, as for me the "it" in our sentence does have an explicit meaning, namely the infinitive phrase in extraposition.

Comment: @AshwinSchumann Btw, I'm wondering if a proNOUN can substitute for an infinitival CLAUSE? :)

Comment: @user178049 I am not an expert in grammatical analysis, so I don't know the answer to your question (btw: why is it an infinitive _clause_, and not a _phrase_?). But I guess the sentence "To hear such rumors is quite common these days." is grammatically correct.

Comment: @AshwinSchumann I'm not an expert either. That's why I'm wondering too. :) Some people also call it a phrase, but most people analyze it as a non-finite clause.

Comment: Or, use another verb, "It happens quite often, to hear..."

Comment: On the other hand some dictionaries (e.g. http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/often) explicitly recognize **"It is not often that (such-and-such happens)"**. This does sound less problematic to me than "It is quite often that ..." but evidently neither "dummy subject" nor "adjective or adverb" tell the full story of what's happening here.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use that sentence structure (which is still passive voice) you must use *common* not *often*.  "Often" is an **adverb** that tells us the frequency of an event *in time*:

> She often comes to this restaurant.
>
> The man doesn't often tell the truth.
>
> That species is not often seen in this climate.

"Common" is an **adjective** that can refer to frequency in time **or** spatial distribution:

> Alligators are common in Florida.
>
> In parts of Los Angeles, it's not uncommon to run into a famous actor while out shopping.
>
> It's common to hear news stories that paint the President in an unflattering light.

Since you use the pronoun "it" as the subject, you must use an adjective and not an adverb.  On the other hand, if you do change it to active voice, you can use "often" to modify the verb "hear":

> We quite often hear such rumors these days.

The same sentence using the passive voice:

> Such rumors are quite often heard these days.

Comment: The occurrence of the phrase _"It is quite often that we hear"_ is not insignificant. As little as I trust the google algo, **[this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It+is+quite+often+that+we+hear%22&tbm=bks)** is significant.

Comment: +1. I think a modern linguist would say something like **often** doesn't license a to-infinitive complement, as, for example, **easy** or **common** do.  It is easy to see...  It is not uncommon to hear...

Comment: And we could combine that with your explanation, to get here:  a word expressing frequency does not combine with a non-finite verb form, in that the non-finite-forms have a quasi nominal existence, which want adjectival predicates.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Interesting.  This is the only example I can think of where "often" effectively functions as an adjective, so perhaps it's just a figure of speech exception (of which English has many)?

Comment: I don't think that construction is peculiar to "often"; I think it works perfectly well to say "It is quite <adverb> that we <verb>" in general.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime  It's like Mad Libs!  "It is quite slithily that we outgrabe."  Yep, that works.

Answer (score 3):

> It is quite often to hear... <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

We can ashcan dummy "it" and twist that around like this, using **to hear**  nominally, since non-finite forms of the verb have *nominal* status (*To err is human*):

> To hear is quite often.  <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

**Often** is not a valid predicate adjective.  It isn't an adjective, but a word expressing frequency.

Another way of putting it is that adverbs (like **often**)  do not license an infinitive complement in the way that adjectives like **easy** and **common** do:

> It is *easy* to see...
>
> It is not *uncommon* to hear...

Answer (score 2):

I apologize that I haven't the skill to offer a definitive grammatical analysis, but is the case of `common vs often` similar to `less vs. few`?

People regularly confuse less (the quantity of a single item, "my toast has less butter than yours...") with few (the quantity of multiple items, "I have fewer sticks of butter than you do...").

In the OP's context, I believe `common` would mean "how frequently everybody does it" (a timeless context) and `often` would mean "how frequently it happens [to me]" (a context based on time).

To maintain the passive voice, the OP's statment would then have to be, "such rumors are heard quite often these days."  Therefore, to answer the OP's question...

Now, here's where the amature really kicks in.  The use of the word `often` is wrong because it's trying to modify the predicate `to hear` but should be modifying the subject `rumors` because you can't quantify `to hear` but you can quantify `rumors`.

Comment: I don't think it's really the same problem as less/fewer. "Less" and "fewer" are the same part speech, whereas "common" and "often" aren't. And I'm not really sure your third paragraph works: something is common if it happens often, regardless of who's doing it. (Though perhaps your "In the OP's context..." is intending to restrict to a more particular case.)

Comment: I believe my problem is that they're often treated as synonyms even though they usually aren't.  Something can happen often, but that doesn't make it common.  Something can be common, even though it doesn't happen often.  I agree that they're different parts of speech as they modify different kinds of words (which is basically the point of my last paragraph), which is why I said "similar" not "same".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you use the verb "to be" you need to add a [predicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression#Predicative_.28adjectival_or_nominal.29), such as a noun or an adjective, to describe *what* the subject is. An example using adjectives is

> It's quite often **sad/scary/reassuring** to hear such rumors these days.

And an example using nouns is:

> It's quite often **a surprise / a nightmare / a miracle** to hear such rumors these days.

If you don't notice the problem with the original sentence, maybe the following trick can help.
In all these sentences, the logical subject is the phrase "to hear such rumors these days". Try to change the order, putting this phrase at the beginning, thus getting rid of the "it", and at the same time removing other unnecessary parts ("quite" and "these days"): the "core" of the sentence is

> To hear such rumors is often.

Do you notice, now, that something is missing? It would be natural to ask: "...It is often *what*?"

So, you need a predicative. A possible solution, [as Ashwin Schumann suggested](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/136174/30156), is to replace "often" (which is an adverb and can't be a predicative) with "common" (which is an adjective and therefore can):

> It's quite **common** to hear such rumors these days.

An alternative solution, if you don't want to change the word "often", is to use another verb, for example "happens" instead of "is":

> It **happens** quite often to hear such rumors these days.

This verb doesn't require a predicative and therefore the sentence is correct.